# Are Servlets suitable for composite operations?

Tags: java, servlets, thread-safety

Servlets are non-threadsafe, the state could be lost between methods calls by different requests.

But can i persist the state between own Servlet's methods during the **single** request safely to implement composite operations?

Like this:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServletRequest {

    private String var;

    void addH() {
        var += "h";
    }

    void addI() {
        var += "i";
    }

    void doGet(...) {
        addH();
        addI();
        // var = "hi"?
    }
}
```

Will the `var` contain the correct value in this case even with concurrent requests? In other words, does it work as Stateless Bean in EJB does?

Comment: try it! make two requests and see what happens

Comment: @daniel, it's noticeable only by using concurrent requests, have no idea how to :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.  Like you said, servlets are not threadsafe.  There's no protected "space" that a request lives in.  So multiple threads (and thus requests) can hit `var` at the same time.  If you want such a protected "space" you need to either synchronize `doGet()` (which of course will destroy concurrency) or do something like using `ThreadLocal` so that each thread (and thus request) will have its own separate copy of instance-wide state.

If you don't need the state to persist outside of requests, you could just create the state within `doGet()` and pass it to the other methods:

```
void doGet(...) {
    StringBuilder var = new StringBuilder();
    addH(var);
    addI(var);
    resp.write(var.toString());
}

void addH(StringBuilder var) {
    var.append('h');
}

void addI(StringBuilder var) {
    ver.append('i');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServletRequest {

    private String var = "";

    void addH() {
        var += "h";
    }

    void addI(long dontAnswerBefore) {
        while(System.currentTimeMillis() < dontAnswerBefore) {
          // Do nothing 
        }
        var += "i";
    }

    void doGet(...) {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        addH();
        addI(now + 10_000);
        resp.write(var);
    }
}
```

This should get you 10 Seconds to make two Requests within two tabs or two different browsers.